# Веб-сервис с переменным количеством параметров

Tags: java-ee

Задача стоит создать веб-сервис с переменным количеством агрументов. На вход могут приходить от 2 до 20 строк. Как должна выглядеть сигнатура метода?

Comment: @ttt, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
public void doSomething(String... args)
{
    for (String s : args) 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```